# Oracle Traces Pros and Cons

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Can anyone please tell me the pros and cons of oracle traces. If we enable the traces what will be the impact on the query execution. Will it effect the performance of DataBase.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by `oracle traces` you mean `sql tracing`. If so, then if you enable `sql tracing` for entire instance it will have a significant impact on performance. It's better to enable sql tracing in scope of a session   `Alter session set sql_trace=true`. But, starting from Oracle 10g upward, parameter `SQL_TRACE` is deprecated.
It's better to use [DBMS_MONITOR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_monitor.htm#i1003993) package.

Comment: I believe from Oracle 7.3 and above the oracle trace has been enabled by default.Can we disable the oracle trace log generation by modifying the listner.ora file like adding an environment variable ENVS='EPC_DISABLED=TRUE'. Will it work with 10g. What I have observed from the session browser from TOAD is that whenever a query is executing it is generating a trace log in the path cd$ORACLE_HOME/diag/rdbms/trace/abc_ora_122.trc. So will this have impact on DB performance. Please clarify